# Siteminder SSO with SSRS 2016

Tags: reporting-services, single-sign-on, siteminder, ssrs-2016

We are doing some analysis for one of our clients who would like to use Siteminder sso with SSRS 2016, we are not finding the ReportManager folder in SQL Reporting service installed location,

Also if there is any way to implement the custom security extension, to authenticate and authorized for reports using site minder sso..

Appreciate any help...

Thanks...